# what's the best way to get notified when entity updates (when saved) in Core Data?

Tags: ios, core-data

There's an article object that I am trying to keep monitoring in one ViewController. From my research there are couple of ways to achieve this but I am not sure which one is the most suitable one:

1, let the ViewController (or repository or viewModel if we are talking about clean architecture) be an observer to listen to the notification when core data saves.

2, in my Core Data abstract layer, add a completion block callback for when `save()` is called.

3, Use NSFetchedResultsController. I know this is designed for UITableView and UICollectionView, but I have seen people use this just to do the monitoring.

Among these 3 paths I am incline towards the third one but I am not 100% sure if that's the best practice since most people use it 1 to 1 on UITableView or UICollectionView.

Comment: I have no good answer but there's a very good WWDC 2018 video on core data best practices that might help here.

Comment: @matt I will take a look at it, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to observe when the object is *changed*, 1 and 2 will not necessarily help you.

You could do 3 - `NSFetchedResultsController` is very powerful - but you could also do the same thing that `NSFetchedResultsController` does internally, and it might be simpler:

**You could register as an observer of `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange`.**

It's posted once per pass through the run loop, if changes have been made, after the side-effects of such changes have been worked out. So it's safe to use if many changes are expected -- you'll only be notified once -- and double-ended relationships will be consistent.

It has a rich `userInfo` dictionary. Your task could be as simple as: check the userInfo's `NSUpdatedObjectsKey` and `NSRefreshedObjectsKey` for your object, and if it's there, refresh the views. Then check `NSDeletedObjectsKey` and `NSInvalidatedObjectsKey` too, and if your object is there, dismiss the view controller or return it to an "empty" state.

Comment: is the `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange` way you suggested basically same as my 1 option? so what I mean in 1 is the VC registers as an observer of `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave`. It may be my mistake forgetting talking about I don't want to care about any changes that has not been saved from the context. So compare your suggestions 3 and 1, would you still prefer 1? (`NSManagedObjectContextDidSave`)

Comment: Not quite the same. `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave` tells you that some context has saved. `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange` tells you that objects in the context that you're observing have changed. If a background context saves, and those changes are expected to be merged into your UI context, that might happen before **or** after your VC sees `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave`. (observers aren't called in any particular order.) But `NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange` will happen as a *result* of that merging, so it's guaranteed to happen after, when the changes will be visible.